# Existence of net of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, order-theory

Does for every totally ordered infinite set $T$ with no greatest element, there exist a net $(a_t )_{t\in T}$ of positive real numbers which is convergent to $0.$ ?

Comment: yes, it you take $a_t=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: But the numbers $a_t $ have to be positive

Comment: Set $T = \mathbb{Z}$.  No such net.  Unless I'm missing something in your conditions for $T$.

Comment: If I define $a_k =|k|^{-1} , a_0=1 $ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $a_k\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible.  Consider the [least uncountable ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) $\omega_1 = \{ \alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$.  This set is totally ordered by $<$ and has no upper bound.  It is known that there can be no strictly monotone net of real numbers indexed by $\omega_1$ (If $\langle a_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha < \omega_1}$ were strictly increasing, then for each $\alpha < \omega_1$ pick a rational number $q_\alpha$ with $a_\alpha < q_\alpha < a_{\alpha+1}$.  How many $q_\alpha$s have we chosen?)

If $\langle a_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha < \omega_1}$ were a net of positive real numbers converging to $0$ it follows that there is an uncountable (and [cofinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality)) $A \subseteq \omega_1$ such that the sub-net $\langle a_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \in A}$ is strictly decreasing (and converges to $0$). Now modify an observation given above to get a contradiction.

Comment: How You construct such strictly decreasing sub-net $\langle a_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \in A}$ ?

Comment: @FisiaiLusia: Inductively construct a strictly increasing "sequence" $\langle \alpha_\xi \rangle_{\xi < \omega_1}$ in $\omega_1$ so that for $\xi < \omega_1$ we have $0 < a_\alpha < a_{\alpha_\xi}$ for any $\alpha_{\xi+1} \leq \alpha < \omega_1$, and for limit $\delta < \omega_1$ take $\alpha_\delta = \lim_{\xi < \delta} \alpha_xi = \sup_{\xi < \delta} \alpha_\xi$.  Then take $A$ to be the range of this sequence.